# Storing JSON objects is Redis when I only care about the key

Tags: node.js, redis, amazon-sqs

General:

I am building something that I plan to use Redis for deduplication. What is happening is a whole bunch of systems are creating AWS SQS messages which are put into Redis via a Lambda function. I want to be able to query Redis every minute and get back all results for a particular ID which is gotten from another system. I will then be checking to see if multiple come back and act on either an array of results or a single result.

Rough design:

What I have in the SQS message that is put into Redis is a JSON object which contains a bunch of data that while sometimes large isn't exactly a concern for this. My Lambda function that loads into Redis extracts a certain ID from the SQS message JSON and uses that as a key.

Question:

My question comes in how should I be setting this up on the Redis side of things? IE what data type how to set the data? I was told hashs but that seems a bit silly since I don't need to read the data in the 'value' side of things. I am open to it that is just my inital thoughts when looking at the Redis docs and other StackOverflow posts.

Requirements:

- Has the entire JSON payload that I can get back when I query for an ID
- When I query for an ID I want to get back all instances of that ID
- Data must expire after 1 minute
- Each ID must be able to appear more than once

Comment: Which data should expire after a minute? Specific instance or all the instances of a specific ID?

Comment: @GuyKorland I want it to be per instance/record. Idea is that the Lambda puts something into Redis and that exact thing will be gone 1 minute later. There is the possibility of overlap of the keys so I can't have it expire all of a certain key.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Redis streams](https://redis.io/commands#stream) for that:

```
XADD myid * json '{"a":1}'
XADD myid * json '{"b":2}'
EXPIRE myid 60
XREAD STREAMS myid 0-0
```

Above code will expire *all* data stored under the ID after 60 seconds. If you want per-entry instead of per-ID expiry then:

1. Use `XREAD STREAMS myid 1604477862794` where `1604477862794` is Unix time minus 60 seconds
2. Use `XRANGE` together with `XDEL` to remove stale (expired) entries

Comment: For the expiring, you mention using commands to expire and remove stale entries, is this not something I can have done automatically by redis? I really don't want to have to manage something to expire things for me. Also this doesn't seem like an option I can do as the redis package on npm doesn't support streams from what I see. I am using Node.js and the offical package to handle Redis so anything I do has to be within that package